# Problem with an exponential decay

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

May someone give me a hint for part (b) please?

> Radiocarbon dating can be used to estimate the age of material, such as animal bones or plant remains, that comes from a formerly living organism. When the organism dies, the amount of carbon-$14$ in its remains decays exponentially. Suppose that $f(t)$ is the amount of carbon-$14$ in an organism at time $t$ (in years), where $t=0$ corresponds to the time of death of the organism. Assume that the amount of carbon-$14$ is modelled by the exponential decay function
>   $$ f(t) = Ce^{kt}\quad (t\geqslant 0),
> $$
>   where $C$ is the initial amount of carbon-$14$ and $k$ is a constant.
>
> The half-life (or halving period) of a radioactive substance like carbon-$14$ is the time that it takes for the amount of the substance to decrease to half of its original level
>
> $(a)$ Given that the half-life of carbon-$14$ is $5730$ years, show that the value of the constant $k$ is $-0.000121$, correct to three significant figures.
>
> $(b)$ Suppose that some ancient animal bones have been found where the amount of carbon-$14$ is known to have decreased to $1/5$ of the level that was present immediately after the death of the animal. How much time has elapsed since the death of this animal? Give your answer to the nearest number of whole years.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can set $C$ to $1$ as everything is proportional.  You are asked to solve $\frac 12=e^{-kt}$ and $\frac 15=e^{-kt}$  You use the $k$ from a for b

Comment: So do I solve it by simultaneous equation?

Comment: No, a gives you one equation in the unknown $k$.  You are given $t$ and $f(t)=\frac C2$, so the $C$s divide out.  In b you know $k$ and need to solve for $t$ given that $f(t)=\frac C5$

Answer (score -1):

I am not using the given formula

Let the number of times C-14 under goes decaying be n,

Therefore, C(1-1/2)^n = C/5 => 1/2^n = 1/5 => n = log 2(base) 5 = 3.01

Hence, Number of years = 3.01*5730 = 13,304.6 = 13305 years (approx.)